# Is it possible to add BitmapData to a NetStream publishing to a FMS?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video-streaming, bitmapdata, netstream

Simple setup:
Actionscript3/Flash application for Augmented Reality. 
A webcam feed is published to a Flash Media Server. 
Now I want the Augmented Reality layer to be a part of this video capture, rendered into one NetStream.

Has anyone done something like adding a watermark to a NetStream before?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send arbitrary data over connection made with `NetConnection`, however, you cannot really affect the video captured from a camera and broadcast in this way. You could however generate video stream using AS and write it to any connection, NetConnection including, yet not if you are using NetStream. Also note that encoding the video in the later way will probably be very computationally expensive and is a less trivial task to program.

Answer (score 0):

you would have to encode it somehow. remember that the video stream is being encoded/transcoded on the fly either by software or hardware.
I have added watermarks to live streams before but only for big events where the stream was coming through a hardware/software mixing deck, altering the stream before it gets to the encoder.

PS. I wish I was working on your project sounds fun.

Comment: Thank you both for the replys. I will do it via NetStream.send. Everytime the Image is tracked, the resulting rotation and translation of the object is stored into the Netstream. This way on playback the information is broadcasted as well and I can recreate the same 3d scene animation.